# pyqt4 not updating layouts and widgets

Tags: python, layout, pyqt4, qwidget, qlayout

I'm designing a checkout window, where the user clicks a buttons to add products and when a button is pressed the layout needs to be updated with current items in the basket, I'm using a window with a splitter & I want the rightside to be updated everytime a button is pressed, but for some reason! It doesn't update, but the product gets updated into the basket dictionary!!

```
class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.basket = []

        vbox = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)

        self.topleft = QtGui.QFrame(self)
        self.topleft.setFrameShape(QtGui.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.topleftfill()

        self.right = QtGui.QFrame(self)
        self.right.setFrameShape(QtGui.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.rightfill()

        self.bottomleft = QtGui.QFrame(self)
        self.bottomleft.setFrameShape(QtGui.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.bottomleftfill()

        splitter1 = QtGui.QSplitter(QtCore.Qt.Vertical)
        splitter1.addWidget(self.topleft)
        splitter1.addWidget(self.bottomleft)

        splitter2 = QtGui.QSplitter(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        splitter2.addWidget(splitter1)
        splitter2.addWidget(self.right)

        vbox.addWidget(splitter2)
        self.setLayout(vbox)
        splitter1.setSizes([100,620])
        splitter2.setSizes([960,360])


    def topleftfill(self):
        lineEdit = QtGui.QLineEdit()
        label = QtGui.QLabel('Search')
        label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        font = QtGui.QFont("Unique", 50, QtGui.QFont.Bold)
        label.setFont(font)
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(label)
        layout.addWidget(lineEdit)
        self.topleft.setLayout(layout)

    def bottomleftfill(self):        
        def producttypes():
            with sqlite3.connect('Example.db') as db:
                cursor = db.cursor()
                cursor.execute('select Type from ProductType')
                result = cursor.fetchall()
                return result

        def typeitems(itemtype):
            with sqlite3.connect('Example.db') as db:
                cursor = db.cursor()
                cursor.execute('select ProductTypeID from ProductType where Type=?', (itemtype,))
                typeid = cursor.fetchall()
                cursor.execute('select Name from Product where ProductTypeID=?',(typeid[0][0],))
                items = cursor.fetchall()
                return items

        typetab = QtGui.QTabWidget(self)
        types = producttypes()

        for name in types:
            tab = QtGui.QWidget()
            typetab.addTab(tab, name[0])
            products = typeitems(name[0])
            typetablayout = QtGui.QGridLayout()
            width = 5
            length = math.ceil(len(products)/5)
            item = 0
            for row in range(length):
                for column in range(width):
                    try:
                        button = QtGui.QPushButton(products[item][0])
                        button.setObjectName(products[item][0])
                        button.clicked.connect(self.addProduct)
                        typetablayout.addWidget(button, row, column)
                        item += 1
                    except IndexError:
                        break
            tab.setLayout(typetablayout)

        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(typetab)
        self.bottomleft.setLayout(layout)

    def rightfill(self):
        label = QtGui.QLabel('Basket')
        label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        font = QtGui.QFont("Unique", 25, QtGui.QFont.Bold)
        label.setFont(font)
        row = 0
        itemslayout = QtGui.QGridLayout()
        for item in self.basket:
            label = QtGui.QLabel(item)
            print(item)
            itemslayout.addWidget(label, row, 3)
            row += 1

        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(label)
        layout.addLayout(itemslayout)
        self.right.setLayout(layout)

    def addProduct(self): 
        product = self.sender().objectName()
        self.basket.append(product)
        basket = collections.Counter()
        for item in self.basket:
            basket[item] += 1
        self.rightfill()
```

Comment: You don't appear to be deleting any of the existing widgets or layouts - maybe you should show a more complete example.

Comment: Yes, it looks like you may need to delete the existing top-level layout of the `right` splitter and all its child widgets first. See [this previous answer of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26220945/984421) for how to do that.

Comment: well, your example would normally work, but QLabel does not have a deleteLater function, therefore an error is throw, any work around it? or should I use try and except? but that is not very efficient

Comment: The `deleteLater` function is provided by `QObject`, and so `QLabel` certainly does have it, because it inherits `QObject`. How are you using my `deleteLayout()` method? It should be added to the `Window` class, and then used at the beginning of `rightfill`, like this: `self.deleteLayout(self.right.layout())`.

Comment: sorry i had a typo in the code, it is working now but when it populates again the order is muddled up and the label never gets populated do you know why?

Comment: I figured out why, `layout.addWidget(label)` after the items haven't been put into the grid for some reason does not display it!, so i called `layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(label)` before the grid